# Ace editor error in setting language mode and theme

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide, ace-editor

I loaded [ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/) via bower, and I can create an editor just fine. However, I can't seem to be able to set the theme and language mode. These are my include lines:

```
    script(src='components/ace-builds/src/ace.js')
    script(src='components/ace-builds/src/mode-xml.js')
    script(src='components/ace-builds/src/theme-solarized_light.js')
```

This is my error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cssText' of null ace.js:12316
afterLoad ace.js:12316
(anonymous function) ace.js:12307
_require ace.js:94
req ace.js:152
(anonymous function) ace.js:12303

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mode' of null ace.js:5309
done ace.js:5309
_require ace.js:94
req ace.js:152
(anonymous function) ace.js:5302
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the way you set mode.
most likely you are doing something like `session.setMode("components/ace-builds/src/mode-xml.js")` but ace can't find mode with that path.
You should call it like `session.setMode("ace/mode/xml")` instead.